# How to inject a string with the same name as Class using Zend\Di

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I am trying to use `Zend\Di\Di` to inject a string into my constructor that happens to have the same name as a class. I am trying to inject the string `"DateTime"` in the constructor but `Zend\Di\Di` thinks it is a class and is trying to create it instead of just injecting the string. If I change the string to `"date_time"`, it is correctly injected without errors as a string.

Interestingly, if I change the string to `"datetime"`, `Zend\Di\Di` spews out tons of errors instead.

Here is my entire file:

```
<?php
include __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
class Foo {
    public function __construct($datatype) {
        $this->datatype = $datatype;
    }
}
$di = new Zend\Di\Di();
$di->configure(new Zend\Di\Config([
    'instance' => [
        'Foo' => [
            'parameters' => [
                'datatype' => 'date_time' // <-- This value.
            ]
        ]
    ]
]));
var_dump($di->get('Foo')->datatype);
?>
```

This leaves me with two questions:

- How can I force `Zend\Di\Di` to treat the data as a specific type?
- Should I report any of this behavior (especially the behavior with `"datetime"`) as a bug?

---

#### Edit

In light of ZF 2.4 deprecating `Zend\Di` in favor of `Zend\ServieManager`, I will not be using `Zend\Di` moving forward. However, I will leave this question here hoping that somebody can answer it and then anybody with the same question can benefit from it.